# Where is the V8::Isolate definition?

Tags: c++, v8

This is all in reference to the JavaScript V8 engine.
Where does the V8::Isolate class get defined? in the code ([api.cc](http://thlorenz.com/v8-dox/build/v8-3.25.30/html/d5/d7a/api_8cc_source.html#l06592)):

```
i::Isolate* isolate = new i::Isolate(false);
```

the isolate is created from the v8::internal::isolate class. Here's the casting into the v8::isolate object.

```
Isolate* Isolate::New(const Isolate::CreateParams& params) {
  i::Isolate* isolate = new i::Isolate(false);
  Isolate* v8_isolate = reinterpret_cast<Isolate*>(isolate);
  ...
}
```

Does anyone know where this class is being defined?

Comment: V8 is open-source, why not download it and search the header files?

Comment: I've been looking for a while now and I just don't understand how it's returning that type when it's not defined anywhere, except the v8.h file, which it's not being included into the api.cc file.

Comment: Maybe some other header file include the correct header file?

Answer (score 0):

There are two `Isolate` classes. The `v8::Isolate` class, which is a part of the public interface, is declared in `include/v8.h`. The `v8::internal::Isolate` class, which is the actual isolate, is declared in `src/isolate.h`.

Comment: The api.cc or api.h doesn't actually #include the src/isolate.h file anywhere... how is it being referenced?

Comment: Sorry, correction, it doesn't #include the include/v8.h file, not the src/isolate.h

Comment: `api.h` includes `src/v8.h`, which in turn includes `include/v8.h`; its easy to spot. Generally, if you're unsure where and how a file is included in some compilation, rerun the compilation with the same command line arguments, but adding an `-E` and look in the output for the first occurance of `# 1 <file-name-here>`